# Starting to us ProjectLocker - new to SVN

Tags: svn, projectlocker

I have never used SVN, but am familiar with some SM (source safe a looong time ago). The project is a web-based project hosted with an ISP (hosting.com). The group I'm working with is using Dreamweaver, and I found a tutorial for using SVN, but I have what I'm sure are some really basic questions...

1) What is the best way to get the files from ISP to projectlocker? (initial check in)

2) I currently save the file locally, then upload (put) with DW. Will I need to do a put to projectlocker, then a separate put to the server?

3) Can someone explain how I can manage the versioning?

I know these are really wide open questions. If some has a good M for the RTFM solution please advise. I'm trying to get in at the "for dummies" level with a "bible" resource I can go to later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much everything you need in terms of Dreamweaver SVN functionality is in Adobe's [Using Subversion with Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/using_subversion_pt1.html) tutorial.

You'll need to get the files from your ISP down to a local path on your machine before committing them to SVN.

The process of committing to source control is independent of that to publishing to a web server. You'll (hopefully) commit very frequently to Subversion compared to publishing to your hosting provider.

You might also find [The 10 commandments of good source control management](http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/05/10-commandments-of-good-source-control.html) useful.